# 2006 USAMO P6: Prove that the circumcircles of triangles $SAE$, $SBF$, $TCF$, and $TDE$ pass through a common point

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, solution-verification

Let $ABCD$ be a quadrilateral, and let $E$ and $F$ be points on sides $AD$ and $BC$, respectively, such that $AE/ED = BF/FC$. Ray $FE$ meets rays $BA$ and $CD$ at $S$ and $T$ respectively. Prove that the circumcircles of triangles $SAE$, $SBF$, $TCF$, and $TDE$  pass through a common point.

Since this was an exercise for spiral similarity, I knew that this problem would use spiral similarity !! Please send your solutions too. This helps me a lot. Thanks in advance.

**My Proof**:Let $O$ be the spiral center of the spiral symmetry $S$ that sends $AD\rightarrow BC \implies S: A\rightarrow B $ and  $S:D\rightarrow C$ . Then since $AE/ED = BF/FC$, we  get that $S:E\rightarrow F$ .

Hence $S:AE \rightarrow BF $. Hence $O$ is the spiral center of the spiral similarity $S$, that sends $AE\rightarrow BF \implies O \in  (SAE)$ and $O\in (SBF)$ as  $AB\cap EF=S$

Similarly , $S:ED \rightarrow FC \implies O \in  (TED)$ and $O\in (TFC)$  as  $DC\cap EF=T$

Hence $(SAE)$, $(SBF)$, $(TCF)$, and $(TDE)$  pass through  common point $O$ which is the spiral center of the spiral symmetry $S$ that sends $AD\rightarrow BC$.

[image]

Comment: I guess she is asking for proof verification ..

Comment: There's a `proof-verification` tag by the way :)

Comment: You should try posting on https://artofproblemsolving.com/

Comment: @Ekesh , I disagree,  AOPS is great for getting problems via contest collections but nobody looks at your unless you are a very popular olympiad math  solver. Just my POV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could write which theorems you use, othervise it is perfect.

I suggest you to try this problem from IMO 2005 also:

Let $ABCD$ be a fixed convex quadrilateral with $BC=DA$ and $BC$ not parallel with $DA$. Let two variable points $E$ and $F$ lie of the sides $BC$ and $DA$, respectively and satisfy $BE=DF$. The lines $AC$ and $BD$ meet at $P$, the lines $BD$ and $EF$ meet at $Q$, the lines $EF$ and $AC$ meet at $R$.

Prove that the circumcircles of the triangles $PQR$, as $E$ and $F$ vary, have a common point other than $P$.

Comment: okay, I will try it too. thanks .

Comment: I tried IMO 2005 .. it is purely simplified once a person knows about spiral symmetry and miquel point . The common point is $(PBC) \cap (PAD)$